# How to set a dynamic RoleMappings key for a IndentityPoolRoleAttachment in CloudFormation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I am building a stack to initialize a `Cognito` installation. As part of this I have setup user groups with associated roles. I need to set the `Choose role from token` option, allowing identities to use roles from the group(s) to which they are assigned.

This is done through the `RoleMappings` object in the `IndentityPoolRoleAttachment` object. This mappings object is a `string -> object` map, where the string represents the identity provider. In my case, this is:

`cognito-idp.${some-region}.amazonaws.com/${some-userpool-id}:${some-pool-client-id}`

Obviously, this needs to be dynamically built based on values in the stack, but I havent found a way to do this in a syntactically correct manner. Using `Ref` and `Fn::Sub` both result in syntactical errors. I have tried in both yaml and json syntax.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible. [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=255584&tstart=0) has a solution though.

Comment: For those wondering, the mentioned thread gathers many users that are facing the same problem and offers a solution using a custom lambda resource. This problems has not been yet resolved by AWS...

Answer (score 2):

Got stuck on this problem recently and I visited [the thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=255584&tstart=0) from @AkkarinZA's comment.

In that thread, @mikef's response worked for me. We can use `cognitoProvider` key.

```
RoleMappings:
     cognitoProvider:
       IdentityProvider: 
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - "cognito-idp.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com/"
            - !Ref CustomerUserPool
            - ':'
            - !Ref CustomerUserPoolClient
       AmbiguousRoleResolution: Deny
       Type: Rules
       RulesConfiguration:
          Rules:
            - Claim: cognito:groups
              MatchType: Contains
              Value: "clients"
              RoleARN:
                { Fn::GetAtt: [UserIdentityPoolClientRole, Arn] }
```