# AWS CloudFormation - Any way to use an intrinsic function as an object key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I have this role attachment resource that as is, deploys just fine:

```
CognitoIdentityPoolRoleAttachment:
  DependsOn: [ CognitoIdentityPool, CognitoIdentityPoolAuthRole, CognitoIdentityPoolUnauthRole ]
  Type: "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment"
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId: !Ref CognitoIdentityPool
    RoleMappings:
      'cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_naEXQTLxD:44rd7mu8dncna2kqimd74f7u98':
        Type: Token
        AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
    Roles:
      unauthenticated: !GetAtt CognitoIdentityPoolUnauthRole.Arn
      authenticated: !GetAtt CognitoIdentityPoolAuthRole.Arn
```

However, as you can see I have a RoleMappings property that is actually my CognitoUserPool ProviderName appended to my Cognito User Pool Client ID, so I need this property to have a dynamic name.

Looking over the docs, however, I can't find a way to actually use intrinsic functions on an object key. When I try this:

```
  RoleMappings:
    !Sub '${CognitoUserPool.ProviderName}:${CognitoUserPoolClient}':
      Type: Token
      AmbiguousRoleResolution: AuthenticatedRole
```

I get an invalid template error. Is there a special syntax I'm missing that allows you to define keys instead of properties? Or am I going to have to do this some other way?

Comment: I think the simplest solution here would be to generate the template using an external script. You can also try creating a custom resource that generates the template and then create a stack from that template with `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack` and the result of that resource.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107620/how-to-set-a-dynamic-rolemappings-key-for-a-indentitypoolroleattachment-in-cloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this out of the box using CloudFormation. 
However, [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=255584&tstart=0) suggests a workaround involving a Lambda-backed custom resource.